# Remove line from text file given first word

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a file of usernames and password for a VPN site I'm making. It looks something like this:

```
#user   #server    #password   #ip
user1   server1    pass1       *
user2   server4    pass67      *
user3   server8    pass32      someip
user9   server1    62pass      *
```

If I have written a simple shell script to append a user to the table, and restart the VPN process:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Adding user $1 with password $2."
echo "$1 l2tpd $2 *" >> /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
echo "Restarting xl2tpd process."
sudo /etc/init.d/xl2tpd restart
echo "VPN restarted, user added."
```

Now what I want to do is write a script that allows me to delete a user from the table, and then restart the process. In order to do this, I have to pass one argument, the username.

How do I lookup the line with that username, and then delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sed`:

```
sed '/^user1/d' filename
```

would remove the line starting with `user1`.  For saving the changes to the file in-place, use the `-i` option.

In order to use a variable, ensure that you use double quotes:

```
sed "/^$1/d" filename
```

---

Alternatively, you might use `grep`:

```
grep -v "^$1" filename
```

Comment: Just tried that, and I get the following error: `sed: 1: "test.txt": undefined label 'est.txt'`

Comment: I worked out why, it needs a semi-colon at the end for some reason :)

Comment: @BenedictLewis - Sed has a command, `t`, which tells it to jump to a label, sort of like the `GOTO` command in BASIC.  Your "undefined label" error tells me that `test.txt` was being interpreted as a command.  You probably need to use a `-e` option to tell sed what part of the command line should be considered the script.  See my answer for an example of `sed -e`.

Answer (score 1):

While a basic `sed` script like devnull's may do the trick, you should be aware that sed searches for a *regular expression*, not a string, and his solution suggests using raw command line content as part of the sed command.

I wouldn't do this.  Input validation is important, because even if no nasty people will gain access to your shell, typos do happen.  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$1" ~ ^[a-z][a-z0-9]*$ ]]; then
  if sed -i.bak -e "/^$1 /d" /etc/ppp/chap-secrets; then
    echo "delete user $1"
  fi
else
  echo "ERROR: Invalid characters.  Please try again." >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

Note that we're testing to make sure that users follow a safe format with no special characters, and we're also making sure that deleting user "foo" doesn't also delete user "foobar" by putting a space after the `$1` in range in the sed script.

I recommend keeping the `-i.bak` in there in case something untoward happens.

Answer (score 0):

if you have gnu sed with -i option.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "deleting user $1."
sed -i "/^$1/d" /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
echo "Restarting xl2tpd process."
sudo /etc/init.d/xl2tpd restart
echo "VPN restarted, user deleted."
```

If not, replace the `sed -i` command with below commands:

```
sed "/^$1/d" /etc/ppp/chap-secrets > temp
mv temp /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
```